# Replace value in element class zoo

Tags: r, zoo, na

I have two time series of the same length of class zoo. One of them as NA value for some dates while the other one is completely filled by value. Since I need to plot some pie charts, I would need to disregard the dates with NA values also in the other time series.

This is what I did:

```
  ind.pos <- which(is.na(a1[,1]) == 'TRUE')

  for (i in ind.pos  ) {
  b1[[i]] <- NA
}
```

Which is working fine. I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish that.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it works, but Hemmo code is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I missed some point, but wouldn' this work:

```
b1[is.na(a1)]<-NA
```

Here your time series are `a1` and `b1` and a1 contains NA's.

Comment: Thanks Hemmo. This is much more efficient.